# WordPressのメディアの一覧を表示し選択画像のURLを取得するプラグインの作り方

Tags: wordpress

画像を扱うさまざまなプラグインで、メディアにアップロードされている画像を選択してURLを取得する機能があるのですが、その実装方法が紹介されているサイトなどあれば教えてください。

投稿ページの「メディアの追加」のような機能をプラグインにつけたいです。

add_mediaでアップロードすることはできるようになったのですが、すでにアップロードされている画像のURLを知る方法が検索しても見つかりません。よろしくおねがいします。

---

もともと投稿にかかれている「メディアの追加」では

メディアを追加

このように書かれているので、このソースコードをそのままプラグインに書くと、なぜかページのトップにただ移動します。自分のプラグインにこの機能を取り付けるにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

実際に試したわけではないのですが、このへんが参考になるのではないでしょうか。
http://jeroensormani.com/how-to-include-the-wordpress-media-selector-in-your-plugin/
http://dobsondev.com/2015/01/23/using-the-wordpress-media-uploader/